# Django: Strange TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I am getting a **"TemplateDoesNotExist at /" error** on Django 1.6.2. Many times covered at Stackoverflow, but nothing worked so far.

The templates are part of their own folder and are not stored in the apps.

```
manage.py
project_dir
|_ settings.py
|_ urls.py
|_ apps
    \_ app1
        \_ views.py
        |_ urls.py
        |_ models.py
|_ templates
    \_ base.html
    \_ pages
         \_ index.html
```

I have set the `TEMPLATE_DIR` and the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` as listed below:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/apps/'))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/templates/'),
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

When I print the folders `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `BASE_DIR`, they are totally ok.
When I copy the printout of `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and view it in the browser directly, I can view the template.

One strange thing I notice is that the loader `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` does not list any folders in the error message. `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` lists some folders related to the apps.

The template is called via the urls.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='app1/index.html'), name='index'),
    ...
)
```

**What is the reason for the template error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, the error is pathetic! I just re-read my `settings.py` again and discovered that there was a  second definition of `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. This overrode all set dirs and also explains why the `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` was empty.

Answer (score 3):

i can't see any "app1/index.html" in the file structure.

Based on what is provided ,  it should be

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/index.html'), name='index'),
```

Comment: I changed the path - no success. Now I have set the absolute path to the template, which I can view in a browser, but Django is still complaining that the file would exist. Are there any file permissions I forgot to set?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a few things? I'd like to see your entire directory setup, including where your `settings.py` is. I'm worried that your `BASE_DIR` or `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is wrong. I would think TEMPLATE_DIRS would just be `'templates'` rather than `'project/templates'` but it could work with your setup.

If that's not it, could you post your `views.py` and the template code you're trying to call?

Comment: I have extended the folder description. I hope it provides more insights. Thank you for your reply.